# Как вывести содержимое xml нода в JFrame?

Tags: java, xmlparser, jframe

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder builder;

try {

    builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(file);
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList methodNodes = root.getChildNodes();
    for(int i=0; i<methodNodes.getLength();i++ )
        methodNodes.item(i).getNodeName();
    Node el = root.getFirstChild();                 
    while(el!=null) {   
//TextAreaNeed
        System.out.print(el.getTextContent());
        el = el.getNextSibling();
    }
```

Как передать `getTextContent()` не в print, а в `JTextArea`, например?

Answer (score 1):

Вызвать метод [append](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) существующего объекта JTextArea.